# Testing a loop behaviour using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The code:

```
def self.api_create(params)
  user_image = UserImage.new(params)
  begin
    user_image.uid = UniqueId.generate[0..7]
  end 

  while not(UserImage.find_all_by_uid(user_image.uid).empty?)
    return user_image
  end
end
```

unique_id is the primary key of UserImage

How can test the following test case?:

```
it "should create a new unique id if the one generated is already in use." do

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
params = ...
user_image = UserImage.api_create(params)
UserImage.find_all_by_uid(user_image.id).should be_empty
```

**after comment**

what about this

```
# first call returns 1, second 2
UserImage.stub!(:find_all_by_uid).and_return(1,2) 

# first call returns 1 so that the method needs another call
UniqueId.stub!(:generate).and_return(1,3)

# let it work (whatever params is)
user_image = UserImage.api_create(params)

# the user id should be 3
user_image.id.should == 3
```

Comment: I want to test the following, if UniqueId.generate[0..7] retrives a uid which is used by some other record, call UniqueId.generate[0..7] again